# “Portal to the past” by slowing light speed

Tags: physics, materials, light, time-manipulation

Light travels at different speeds through different types of media, which causes phenomena such as [refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction) and [Cherenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation). However, in most cases, the light still travels through the medium pretty darn fast.

If we possessed a material that was capable of slowing the propagation of light to a *tiny fraction* of light speed, we might actually be able to notice the delay between light entering and leaving the material. If I walked past an screen covered with this material, someone looking through the screen might *see* me walk past a few minutes after it actually happened. If the material is even more powerful (or fashioned into a thick slab), one could observe events that took place days, months, or even years in the past.

Is such a material theoretically possible? If so, what other strange properties (e.g. refractive properties) would this material have? Is there a limit to *how much* a medium can slow light down?

Comment: might be helpful https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/trapping-light

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_light#Ways_to_achieve_slow_light

Comment: For a well-known fictional treatment of this idea, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_of_Other_Days

Comment: How advanced is the society that is interested in building this sort of thing?

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies as "material", but a video camera on one side, recording device in the middle, and a video screen on the other side technically meets the criteria set in this question.

Comment: Material: space. Lots of it. So much it takes days, months or years to reach you ;)

Comment: @void_ptr My thoughts exactly, what's going on here that couldn't be done with a camera? Now if the "light delay" would occur naturally, that could be really interesting though.

Comment: Now this is a cool idea, especially for a fantasy setting. I'm imagining a non-technologically advanced industry where an event is recorded on "slow glass" by a spy or a reporter and is later re-recorded and many many pieces of smaller slow glass and sold like newspaper. "That's ten nickels, sir." The boy checks his watch and says: "Shows in three hours, ten minutes." I set my watch and pay, setting the heavy slab in my robe.

Comment: There's a whole body of fiction on this subject, going back to the 40's. It's good stuff. A lot of it based around tachyons and the like, though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_viewer

Comment: One thing that concerns me about the idea though is the energy stored in the material. Imagine having a block of the stuff that say delays 3 hours. One could leave it out in the sun and let it radiate at night for a great light source, but all that thermal energy absorbed by the material could potentially be enough to melt it. It could be restricted to say the visible wavelengths, but having longer and longer delays, say whole days or weeks, would make for a lot of energy packed into a relatively small space, i.e., a bomb.

Comment: If an image could be kept discernable traveling through some length of the material, you could construct a loop out of the stuff and attempt to keep an image persisting. You could view the image by introducing a light splitter somewhere in the loop--perhaps a toggleable one--that could split the light into two paths: one for looping and the other for viewing. Trouble is, light could enter the loop through the viewer, so it likely should be kept in a dark place.

Answer (score 5):

We can do this on timescales on the order of 1 minute at the moment, if you'll allow me to stretch the boundaries of the question a bit. There are essentially [two ways to do this](http://physics.wm.edu/%7Einovikova/slowlight.html):

1. *Slow light*, where the refractive index of a medium is drastically increased, in the process slowing down the pulse velocity of a beam of light.
2. *Stored light*, where the quantum states of photons in a laser beam are mapped onto atomic states in a crystal with the help of a second laser, and then converted back into photon states.

The second example is potentially more fruitful, and it is this method which enabled physicists ([Heinze et al. 2013](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.111.033601); pdf [here](https://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.111.033601)) to "store" light for one minute inside a 3-millimeter Pr<sup>3+</sup>:Y<sub>2</sub>SiO<sub>5</sub> crystal:

[image: Diagram of the Heinze et al. experiment]

<sup>Figure 1(a), Heinze et al. 2013. The setup for light storage is much more complex than you presumably want, and involves many different optical elements.</sup>

Part of the reason the team was able to achieve such long storage times was their use of evolutionary algorithms to find an optimal pulse shape; these algorithms could potentially be extended in the future to reach longer timescales. Unfortunately, any storage mechanism will be subject to optical losses, and will be limited by the simple fact that it isn't an ideal environment.

There are, of course, some caveats. For example, the light being stored comes from a laser, so you would need a large bank of lasers to slow down complex images. You also have the issue that only one pulse is being stored in each crystal at once, and that pulse doesn't represent a long snapshot of time. Plus, the storage efficiency is not great - 0.4% by Heinze et al., with the possibility of doubling it to 1% if certain technical problems can be accounted for.

The upshot, though, is that yes, we can indeed see store light for noticeable timescales. The efficiency is poor, and the light has to come in the form of a laser, but it can be done, and it can presumably be improved upon.

Answer (score 1):

Read Bob Shaws SF Novel *'Other days Other Eyes'* which revolves around the invention of a product called 'Slow Glass' - sheets of a transparent glass like material that slow the speed of light down so that events that occurred on one side of the 'glass' can take days, weeks. months, years or decades etc depending on the thickness of the sheet and other factors to reach the other side. The implications turn out to be both intriguing and at a human level tragic.